# Nextflow Forcibly marking a task as complete

Tags: nextflow

there has been a lot of discussion of pipelines that use a lot of space and delete intermediate files on nextflow automatically and for all pipelines. My question is related but given that no one has given an aswer i was wondeing if i can somehow mark a task as done.

The reason is that i'm explcitly deleting the output of an intermediate step in a consuming process once i don't need it anymore and putting a an empty file in place with the same name. Apparently it fools the process that generates it, but not the process that consumes it. When i run the pipeline again with -resume it re-runs the consuming process. does nextflow checks for timestamps of files?

is there a way to say don't run the process anymore for this input, and continuing for the rest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default cache keys are created by indexing the name, size and last update timestamp attributes of input files (this can be changed using the [`cache`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cache) directive). But for what you want, you might be more interested in testing out [#3818](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/pull/3818) (from [#452](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/452)), which adds a `temporary` option to `path` outputs. The example given [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/452-temporary-outputs/tests/temporary-outputs.nf) looks like:

> ```
> process foo {
>     input:
>     val meta_id
>     output:
>     tuple val(meta_id), path('a.txt', temporary: true)
>
>     script:
>     """
>     touch a.txt
>     echo 'foo was here' >> a.txt
>     """
> }
> ```

> ```
> process bar {
>     input:
>     tuple val(meta_id), path('a.txt')
>     output:
>     tuple val(meta_id), path('b.txt', temporary: true)
>
>     script:
>     """
>     cat a.txt > b.txt
>     echo 'bar was here' >> b.txt
>     """
> }
> ```

> ```
> process baz {
>     publishDir '.'
>
>     input:
>     tuple val(meta_id), path('a.txt'), path('b.txt')
>     output:
>     tuple val(meta_id), path('c.txt')
>
>     script:
>     """
>     cat b.txt > c.txt
>     echo 'baz was here' >> c.txt
>     """
> }
> ```

> ```
> workflow {
>     meta_ids = Channel.of( '1', '2', '3' )
>     ch_a = foo(meta_ids)
>     ch_b = bar(ch_a)
>     ch_ab = ch_a.join(ch_b)
>     ch_c = baz(ch_ab)
> }
> ```

> After the first run, we inspect the work directory and find that all
> of the output files that were declared with `temporary: true` in the
> pipeline are now empty. On a resumed run, everything is cached. In
> this case, a run can be safely resumed as long as all of the `baz` can
> be cached. If you modify the `baz` process or delete/modify any of the
> `c.txt` files, resuming the run will produce incorrect output.

Comment: Was this implemented in DSL 2 ? I am running Nextflow 23.10.0 and cannot get this syntax to work